# Optimise images in AEM

Tags: aem

We are using AEM 6.2 and want to optimise multiple images in AEM to get a low resolution image. Please suggest how can we get low resolution images upon uploading the images or some other way.

Comment: Why don't you use ootb Image renditions?

Comment: By default, AEM creates renditions for assets. You can use them, and you can customize the workflow for creating different resolutions and formats. For more specialized renditions you may take a look at Dynamic Media or similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ACS commons, explore [named-image-transform](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/named-image-transform/index.html) else you have to generate custom renditions using Workflows.

If you already have an Dynamic media add on , try to leverage [smart imaging](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-64/assets/dynamic/imaging-faq.html#am-i-eligible-to-use-smart-imaging)

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `ImageMagick` and modify the DAM Asset Workflow to create low-resolution images renditions.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/assets/using/best-practices-for-imagemagick.html

Thanks!